# Downgrade attack prevention - IBM HTTP Server Changes

Tags: security, ssl, ibmhttpserver

I am currently seeing a vulneribility post scanning for Downgrade Prevention Attack on my website, I did a quick check on google and figured out TLS Fallback Signaling Cipher Suite Value (SCSV) can be used for Preventing Protocol Downgrade Attacks,

But can anyone suggest what changes will i have to make to my IBM HTTP server conf files to prevent this vulneribilty. If not how can we implement TLS Fallback Signaling Cipher Suite Value (SCSV)

djrecker.

Comment: I think you should try this question on http://security.stackexchange.com/ or http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IHS doesn't support SCSV, which is a protocol that enables browsers to do slightly less unsafe non-TLS negotiation when they see connections abruptly closed.

You could disable SSLv3 so there is no "weak" protocol to allow this to downgrade to.